# external url in webpack alias

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My team moved all the images of company website into a CDN. (https://cdn.irobo.co.kr/images)
However, I'd like to use those images without changing current code base, which has a lot of: (reactjs code)

```
<image src={require('img/common/logo.jpg')} />
```

here's the webpack config for the website:

```
{
  module: {
    loaders:[{
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]',
    }],
  }
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      img: path.join(srcPath, 'app/img'),
    }
  }
}
```

Here's what I tried:

```
...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      img: 'https://cdn.irobo.co.kr/images',
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Webpack compiles the code. While compiling it transforms images, what you want to use is link to images. And download when ui loads.

It can be achieved by <img src={https://cdn.irobo.co.kr/images/${path}}/>

Wild idea : you can write a img loader, that just replaces the image urls.

Answer (score 1):

**Bundling assets from external urls with Webpack**

The url-loader plugin for webpack gives you the ability to take use assets from external url by encoding them in base64.

> The url loader works like the file loader, but can return a Data Url
>   if the file is smaller than a byte limit.
>
> The limit can be specified with a query parameter. (Defaults to no
>   limit)

Remember to install the url-loader plugin as a project dependency.

```
npm install --save-dev url-loader
```

**Configure the url-loader plugin**

Here is a sample webpack config to set up the url-loader plugin.

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './main.js',
  output: {
    path: './build', // This is where the images and js will go
    publicPath: 'http://mycdn.com/', // used to generate URLs to e.g. images
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // use ! to chain loaders
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
      // inline base64 URLs for <=8k images, direct URLs for the rest
      { test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192' }
    ]
  }
};
```

**Import the assets in your app**

*app.jsx*

```
import image from '../build/image.jpg';

<img src={image} />
```